# Check for file creation in a loop

Tags: powershell

Can I run this script one time automate when the .exe show up on folder?

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.exe | ForEach {
    &$_.Fullname /s
```

I want a script to check if .exe file shows up on folder, then run that commands, else check again for .exe file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FileSystemWatcher` to listen for these events.

```
Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier ExeCreated -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Unregister-Event;
$Watcher = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileSystemWatcher;
$Watcher.Filter = '*.exe';
$Watcher.Path = 'c:\test';

$Action = { Write-Host -Object ('New file created: {0}' -f $event.SourceArgs[1].Name); };
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Watcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier ExeCreated;
```